# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '-'

Tags: preg-match

I am working on a Wordpress site and recently I have begun getting this warning:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '-'

It started when I changed the permalink structure to `/%postname%/`, which is needed for BuddyPress to function. If use the default permalink structure, the problem goes away.

Here is the code from the `wp-includes/class-wp.php` where the error is occurring:

```
if ( preg_match("#^$match#", $request_match, $matches) ||
 preg_match("#^$match#", urldecode($request_match), $matches) ) {
```

Comment: what is the content of `$match` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: preg\_replace(): Unknown modifier '\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier)

Answer (score 1):

this is because `-` and `/` are special symbols, you can change this code to:

```
if ( preg_match("/^".preg_quote($match)."/", $request_match, $matches) ||
 preg_match("/^".preg_quote($match)."/", urldecode($request_match), $matches) ) {
```

but I assume that problem is somewhere deeper, in core logic of wp

Comment: Thanks Ilya, but the issue remains. You are most likely correct that the problem lies somewhere deeper.

Comment: issue in the same lines?

Comment: `-` doesn't have a special meaning outside a character class.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes, value has `/` too, so `-` became modifier

Answer (score 0):

Without the `$match` variable content it is difficult to know what the problem is, but if you obtain this warning, it's because `$match` contains `#-` (i.e. the pattern delimiter used and the `-` character). Then all characters after this `#` are seen as modifiers.

You can try to change the delimiter (and pray) to `~`:

```
if ( preg_match("~^$match~", $request_match, $matches) ||
preg_match("~^$match~", urldecode($request_match), $matches) ) {
```

If it doesn't work try other delimiters.